# ServiceStack bundler prefixing semicolons on build

Tags: bundler, servicestack

ServiceStack's Bundler has been prefixing a `;` to our *js/*min.js files on build. This is causing git to think there's a diff unnecessarily. Is this intended behavior?

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue, did you ever resolve it? It also adds a semicolon to the start of the source file, not just the minified file.